# web scraping - refer to element

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get name of the bank and the sum to the pandas dataframe as two columns

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html5lib
import pandas as pd

html_data = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks', timeout=20).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")

newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)'])
for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[3].find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all('td')
    print(col)
```

so the first row is :

```
[
<td>1</td>, 
<td><a href="/wiki/JPMorgan_Chase" title="JPMorgan Chase">JPMorgan Chase</a></td>, 
<td>368.78</td>
]
```

how can i refer to the td inside td? If i want to get bank's name inside td for ex

Answer (score 3):

If you need Dataframe from the wikipedia article, simply use [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html) function:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks")[3]
print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Rank | Bank name | Market cap(US$ billion) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | JPMorgan Chase | 368.78 |
| 1 | 2 | Industrial and Commercial Bank of China | 295.65 |
| 2 | 3 | Bank of America | 279.73 |
| 3 | 4 | Wells Fargo | 214.34 |
| 4 | 5 | China Construction Bank | 207.98 |

Comment: how can i get only bank name and market cap?

Comment: @irenavox You can do `print(df[["Bank name", "Market cap(US$ billion)"]])`